# Why is a particular comparison value causing this sql query to return a ambiguous column error while others do not?

Tags: sqlite

In a node.js/electron/sqlite3 app the following query returns correctly for all states except for 'ID'.

I've dug around for an answer, but all the solutions I've found are for queries that fail completely.

The query in question:

```sql
let stmt_data = 'SELECT DOMAIN, avg(SCORE) from( \
        SELECT Domains.DOMAIN, Indicators.INDICATOR, avg(MetricScores.SCORE) as SCORE \
        FROM MetricScores \
        INNER JOIN Counties ON MetricScores.FIPS == Counties.FIPS \
        INNER JOIN MetricVariables ON MetricScores.METRIC_VAR_ID == MetricVariables.ID \
        INNER JOIN MetricGroups ON MetricVariables.METRIC_GROUP_ID == MetricGroups.ID \
        INNER JOIN Domains ON MetricVariables.DOMAIN_ID == Domains.ID \
        INNER JOIN Indicators ON MetricVariables.INDICATOR_ID == Indicators.ID \
        WHERE Counties.COUNTY_NAME == "' + comp_location['COUNTY_NAME'] + '" AND Counties.STATE_CODE == "' + comp_location['STATE_CODE'] + '" AND METRIC_GROUP == "HWBI" \
        Group By Domains.DOMAIN, Indicators.INDICATOR) Group By DOMAIN';
```

A value of '`ID`' in the query @ `comp_location['STATE_CODE']` results in the following error:

```
SQLITE_ERROR: ambiguous column name: ID
```

I realize it is an issue with columns that have the same name as this value. I am confused as to why changing a comparison value would break this query.

I have found a solution/work-around:

changing

`WHERE Counties.COUNTY_NAME == "' + comp_location['COUNTY_NAME'] + '" AND Counties.STATE_CODE == "' + comp_location['STATE_CODE'] + '" AND METRIC_GROUP == "HWBI"`

to

`WHERE Counties.COUNTY_NAME == ? AND Counties.STATE_CODE == ? AND METRIC_GROUP == "HWBI"`

and passing the variables to

`db.all(sql, [county, state], (err, rows) => {...});`

provides the expected behavior, but I am still interested in why the original sql statement fails.

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers, single quotes are for strings. So `"ID"` is a column name. Stick to the binding values to parameters approach. You also just need `=`, not `==`.

Comment: Thanks, changing to this convention did fix the problem, but it then raises the question: if double quotes means a column, why didn't it throw an unknown column error for a state value other than 'ID' or for the other two values in that part of the query?

Comment: Because of this: https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#double_quoted_string_literals_are_accepted

Comment: This is a great explanation, thanks for the help/link.